# Initialising fields with initial values with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I'm currently trying to work out how to set the initial values for some fields using Ninject.

I have something like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private ISomething _something;

    public SomeClass(string someParam)
    {

    }

    public void DoAThing()
    {
        _something.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

My dilemma comes about in the setting of `_something` to an initial value, given I don't want the class to know anything about which default implementation of `ISomething` to use, is there a way of achieving this in Ninject?

I should add that passing the initial values in via the constructor is not an option.

I should also add that this is in a class-library, so any information on how and when the setup of the kernel & injection should take place would be great :)

**Elaboration: It seems that people could be getting confused, I am not trying to get an ISomething into the class (it isn't a dependency), rather, the default implementation of ISomething is the dependency, this is why I went for the service-locator pattern, for actual dependencies I would of course have them in the constructor.**

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create constructor without parameters that will initialize your field _something or anything else?

Comment: Not entirely, it was more that I wanted a way to grab a default concrete instance of the ISomething interface without having to have SomeClass know anything about the concrete types; I solved it with a service-locator type solution in the end (see answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's not very good to have highly coupled classes, thus depending on abstractions is a good choice. But hiding your dependencies is not very good solution. Make them visible to clients of your class, and use dependency injection to provide concrete implementations of dependencies to your class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private ISomething _something;

    public SomeClass(ISomething something, string someParam)
    {
        _something = something;
    }

    public void DoAThing()
    {
        _something.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Also consider to create factory, which will provide default implementation of `ISomething` to created `SomeClass` objects.

Comment: This would be correct if I was trying to get an ISomething into the class (which simply isn't the case), what I'm trying to do is get a *default* implementation of ISomething (it could be done this way, but then *every* object that needs that default would need to take an ISomething in their constructor).

Comment: I think you are missing understanding of what is dependency, when telling that `ISomething` is not dependency of your class. Dependency is a service that is required by another object to fulfill its function. There is nothing about how dependency created or passed. It could be field, or method parameter. It could be passed to object, or created inside object.

Comment: Yes, but the ISomething is intended to only be internal to the class, it isn't meant to be created elsewhere and passed in, the difficulty comes about because ISomething can have many implementations; are you saying that any other types used count as dependencies regardless of usage and origin and as such should be passed via the constructor?

Comment: @Clint exactly, any object which dependent needs is a dependency, regardless of usage and origin. Its not necessary to pass dependency via constructor (but strongly recommended - it will make dependencies visible, and easily mockable for testing). Sorry, it's 3 AM here.. Will be back tomorrow. Also I recommend for reading very good book http://www.amazon.com/Dependency-Injection-Dhanji-R-Prasanna/dp/193398855X/ref=la_B002XT1PL4_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1354491594&sr=1-1

Comment: I've looked around online and actually your answer helped a lot, the route I'm going is to use constructor injection and factories so that non-injected arguments can be supplied; the service-locator served its purpose for the short term but I see now why it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Clint I'm very glad that you made a great decision :) BTW here is another very good book on this topic http://www.manning.com/seemann/ It has also has a chapter, which describes why Service Locator is an anitpatern

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to go with a static IOC access class to allow my code to gain access to the core Ninject Kernel used by the class library for the main injection.

So:

```
internal static class IOC
{
    private static readonly IKernel _kernel;

    static IOC()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel(new IModule[] {
            new SomethingModule(),
        });
    }

    static T Get<T>()
    {
        return _kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}

internal sealed class SomethingModule : StandardModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISomething>().To<ConcreteSomething>(
            new ConstructorParam("arg", "value"));
    }
}
```

Then in my previous class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private ISomething _something;

    public SomeClass(string someParam)
    {
        _something = IOC.Get<ISomething>();
    }

    public void DoAThing()
    {
        _something.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Now I can get concrete implementations and even have them initialised with default values to boot!

The way of getting the concrete classes initialised with default values is a little flimsy, but I'm sure there are smarter ways of achieving this in Ninject, but it does appear that a hybrid solution of service-locator-esque code and Ninject works quite well!

BTW I believe you could also have multiple IOC containers in differing scopes (themselves passed along via Ninject :P) to prevent creating a behemoth "everything everywhere" kernel.

Hope this helped someone!

Comment: Not very good solution - your class now have strong coupling with static `IOC` class. It hides fact of dependency on `ISomething` from its clients. And its not very testable now. What's wrong to use constructor injection or property injection?

Comment: Property injection is considered bad practice for Ninject now, Constructor injection isn't an option because then *everywhere* in my code that I'm using ISomething I would need to pass in an ISomething representative of the default concrete implementation in every constructor (that would be a major overkill).

Comment: I appreciate that the code now has a strong dependency on the IOC class, but it was going to have to have a strong dependency on the Ninject Kernel at some point along the line; I *could* in turn make the IOC class follow an interface and use Ninject to get to that, but I still end up with needing *a* concrete type to get to the kernel (so an infinite regress occurs) - this way could be made better, but it seems to be the simplest and best way of doing so that I've been able to discover thus far.

Comment: If you are using Ninject, then you don't need to pass default concrete implementation everywhere - ninject will do that.

Comment: Ninject won't do it for fields, only constructors and only when the type is requested through Ninject (directly or as part of a dependency chain); Also, Ninject will not set any defaults for that class (i.e. a string argument on the concrete classes' constructor).